# Is it safe to install an additional memory card while running server?

Tags: 18.04, ram, memory-card

I'm running some service on the Ubuntu 18.04 in which the machine has 16GB memory.

Because of a certain reason, I want to install an additional 16GB of memory.

So, is it safe to install an additional memory card while running my service?

If not, do I have to stop my service, shutdown the Ubuntu machine, install an additional memory card on the machine, restart the machine and restart my service?

Comment: no you should shutdown your machine

Comment: Not only should you shutdown the service and the machine, you should unplug the AC cord, and hold down the power button for 5-10 seconds, to completely drain the PS and any voltage to the memory slots. Also use anti-static procedures when handling the memory... anti-static bracelet or constant contact with ground.

Comment: @wraith3690001 Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: @heynnema Thank you :) Let me investigate more

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you should close the service, and shut down the server, then unplug the power.

Not only does it require shutdown, but a memory test run is highly recommended.   Hold [shift] on startup, then in the menu, choose "Test memory".

Please also consult your motherboard manual for the optimum slot to use to put that memory module into, and use anti-static precautions when handling the memory and installing it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I've never heard `anti-static`. Let me study more

Comment: BTW, then I don't need to reinstall ubuntu right?

Comment: No software reinstall required, but you may wish to adjust yr swap size, esp. if you use hibernation.